# Does netty guarantee order of packets

Tags: netty

I need to know if the asynchronous model of Netty guarantees packet order (on a higher level than layer 4)

For example, in the following code

```
// Assume dos is a DataOutputStream connected to a socket
dos.writeBytes(new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x1, 0x0 });
Thread.sleep(100);
dos.writeBytes(new byte[] { 0x4, 0x1, 0x5, 0x3 });
```

Is there a guarantee that the first set of bytes will arrive before the second, or does Netty group them on a higher level and then push these byte groups concurrently?

Comment: The bytes will always arrive in the order sent. However, they may not be grouped exactly as you sent them as the packets may be fragmented.

Answer (score 2):

Yes order is guaranteed, so nothing to worry about.